# Can you use layered or node-based textures for use outside BI materials?

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine, particles, displacement

I have to confess to being bewildered by Blender's internal texture system, so I may be missing something obvious.

I've just about grasped how the texture stack, and texture nodes work, when associated with a Blender Internal material, but how would you build more complex interactions of procedural textures for use as an influence on particles, or set the heights in a Displacement Modifier? The only option offered seems to be for a single texture?

What will happen to the texture system in 2.8+, when the Blender Internal renderer is culled?

Comment: As far as I know non material textures like modifiers or painting can't use nodes to my knowledge. "*What will happen to the texture system in 2.8*" That is pretty much speculation at this point. Hopefully start using Cycles based Node Compatible setup

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos  I hope so too.. to me, this area is one of the very few in Blender that feels jury-rigged. From the little I know of the way Cycles works, it's hard to imagine an elegant  way of giving textures an independent existence. But there are people out there who know a _lot_ more than me!

Comment: Well they managed to reproduce most of them for realtime viewport preview, maybe a similar high performance OpenGL based technique could be conjured